# Replace alphabets in a string with a character and number with another character in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have string like '`A9Tf6Uv54`', Now I want replace it with '`xzxxzxxzz`' format.

In other words alphabetic characters are replaced with '`x`' and numbers with '`z`'.

How can I replace both numeric and alphabets with different character in SQL?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Try to rephrase it, or provide more input/expected output examples.

Comment: whenever a alphabet is found it has to be replaced with 'x' and numeric with 'z'. Please check the example.

Comment: Please clarify your question by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
DECLARE @StringText VARCHAR(20) =  'A9Tf6Uv54';
DECLARE @digitReplacement VARCHAR(20) =  'z';
DECLARE @letterReplacement VARCHAR(20) =  'x';

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9'+@letterReplacement+']%',@StringText)>0
    SET @StringText = STUFF(@StringText,PATINDEX('%[^0-9'+@letterReplacement+']%',@StringText),1,@letterReplacement)
WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@StringText)>0
    SET @StringText = STUFF(@StringText,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@StringText),1,@digitReplacement)


--RESULT
xzxxzxxzz
```

Answer (score 0):

ifound bug and fix it  -:)

```
declare @r int=1  --pointer to next letter in the string
declare @l int = (select len('A9Tf6Uv54'))
declare @str varchar(100)=''   -- init the new str
declare @x varchar(10)='x'  --replace number
declare @z varchar(10)='z'  --replace char
while @l!=0    --loop ending at the end of the original str
begin
if (ascii(substring('A9Tf6Uv54',@r,1)) between 48 and 57)

begin
set @str=ltrim(@str)+@z
set @l=@l-1
set @r=@r+1
end
else
begin
set @str=ltrim(@str)+@x
set @l=@l-1
set @r=@r+1
end
end
select @str
```

>